# Inserting unicode emoticon symbols doesn't work

Tags: android

[This document](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf) lists emoticons with their unicode character representation:

For example, 1F600 represents a grinning face.

1. I don't understand how a unicode character takes more than 4 hex digits.
2. I am trying to understand if it is possible to use these unicode characters in Android EditText control.

The following text, for example, doesn't work:

```
editText.setText("\u1F600 ");
```

I would appreciate it if someone can tell me what is it that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unicode characters, however, not all of them are present on a given system.  I believe the character set is API level dependent, but I'm not sure.  I got a blank rectangle when I tried to use characters that weren't present.

To browse and insert the characters, I ended up going to (on a Mac) TextEdit->Edit->Special Characters, selecting the characters I wanted, and then copy/pasting the strings into my strings.xml file.  This way, they show up as the character instead of the unicode hex.  Also note that the characters are font dependent, so they will show up slightly differently on different systems.